# Where to setup an API in Vue.js

Tags: api, vuejs2, mixins

I need to use an API that requires initialization with an API key and some other details within my Vue.js app.

```
var client = api_name('app_id', 'api_key', ...)
```

I would need to make several API calls with the `client` object in multiple components in my app

```
client.api_function(...)
```

How can I avoid repeating the initialization step in every component?

I'm thinking about using a global `mixin` in `main.js` for that

```
  Vue.mixin({
      data: function() {
         return {
           get client() {
            return api_name('app_id', 'api_key');
           }
        }
     }
  })
```

Is this a good approach?

Comment: Please mark the answer if it's been the most helpful one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather move your getter to a service and just import, where you actually need it. It doesn't seem to fit into `data` section, more like `methods`. A mixin is a decent approach if you need lots of similar stuff: variables, methods, hooks etc. Creating a mixin for only 1 method looks like overkill to me.

```
// helper.js
export function getClient () {
  // do stuff
}

// MyComponent.vue
  import { getClient } from 'helpers/helper`
  // Vue instance 
  methods: { 
    getClient 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a helper file and writing a plugin that exposes your api url's? You can then create prototypes on the vue instance. Here's an example,

```
const helper = install(Vue){
 const VueInstance = vue
 VueInstance.prototype.$login = `${baseURL}/login`
}
export default helper
```

This way you can access url's globally using **this.$login**. Please note $ is a convention to avoid naming conflicts and easy to remember that it is a plugin.

Comment: I'm not using URLs to interact with the API. The API comes in the form of a module with functions. Take a look at my sample code